# Does the put-call-parity hold for the Heston model?

Tags: black-scholes, heston, replication, put-call-parity

My question is quite simple: Does the Put-Call-Parity hold for the Heston model? My textbook handels the Black-Scholes model with the Put-Call-Parity being

$$p_t = Ke^{-r(T-t)}+c_t-S_t.$$

However, it is not very specific about the assumptions.
Does the same formula apply directly to other models (e.g. the Heston-model) or do we need to modify the formula?

Answer (score 2):

The Put-Call-Parity is a characteristic of the contract universe, not the underlying model. For **European type** options, the parity should always hold (in a liquid market) - else, there'd be an arbitrage opportunity.